# Regular expression to extract either integer or string from JSON

Tags: regex

I am working in [an environment](https://bubble.io/) without a JSON parser, so I am using regular expressions to parse some JSON. The value I'm looking to isolate may be either a string or an integer.

For instance

Entry1

```
{"Product_ID":455233, "Product_Name":"Entry One"}
```

Entry2

```
{"Product_ID":"455233-5", "Product_Name":"Entry One"}
```

I have been attempting to create a single regex pattern to extract the Product_ID whether it is a string or an integer.

I can successfully extract both results with separate patterns using look around with either `(?<=Product_ID":")(.*?)(?=")` or `(?<=Product_ID":)(.*?)(?=,)`

however since I don't know which one I will need ahead of time I would like a one size fits all. 
I have tried to use `[^"]` in the pattern however I just cant seem to piece it together

I expect to receive 455233-5 and 455233 but currently I receive "455233-5"

Comment: Why muck around with regexes? Why not just use a JSON parser?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option for me but I appreciate the idea

Comment: What tool are you using that allows look-behind regexes but does not have a JSON parser?

Comment: bubble.is its a low code development software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<="Product_ID"\s*:\s*"?)[^"]+(?="?\s*,)` 
, try it [here](https://regexr.com/4ddj6).

Comment: I apologise it worked perfectly, your amazing. I really appreciate your help